# Console says onsubmit function doesn't exist for register form, even though it clearly does

Tags: javascript, html, forms, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I have a register form, as thus:

```html
<form name="register" action="" method="POST" onsubmit="register()" autocomplete="off">
...
</form>
```

And I know that every child of this form is functioning.
Then, below in a `<script>` tag I have my main function which is called when the above form is submitted. And I know that everything outside of the `register` function is running. However, when I input random values into each field of my form, and press submit, the console shows that the `register()` function called in the `onsubmit` attribute of my form does not exist. I can't seem to find the problem here:

```
//Global Vars
var firebaseConfig = { ...
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
var db = firebase.firestore();
var registerButton = document.querySelector("#registerButton");
//Main Register Function
function register() {
  event.preventDefault();
  //Locally Global Variables
  var fullName = document.forms["register"]["fullName"].value;
  var username = document.forms["register"]["username"].value.toLowerCase();
  //The MD5 is a way to hash the password, that way the real password is safe and only the hash is used
  var password = md5(document.forms["register"]["password"].value);
  var serviceProvider = document.forms["register"]["serviceProvider"].value;
  //Simple If Statement that adds appropriate email suffix based on Service Provider
  if (serviceProvider === "Verizon") {
    serviceProvider = "@vtext.com";
  } else if (serviceProvider === "ATT") {
    serviceProvider = "@txt.att.net";
  } else if (serviceProvider === "TMobile") {
    serviceProvider = "@tmomail.net";
  } else if (serviceProvider === "Sprint") {
    serviceProvider = "@messaging.sprintpcs.com";
  }
  var phoneNumber = document.forms["register"]["phoneNumber"].value + serviceProvider;
  var emailAddress = document.forms["register"]["emailAddress"].value;
  //Checks The Database If The Username Is Already Taken Or Not
  db.collection("Users").where("username", "==", username).get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
      //Checks Each Individual Result -- If there are no results, than this code will not run
      try {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          //If any result exists, stop here
          if (doc.data()) {
            alert("I'm sorry but this username is already taken!! Please Try Another One");
            throw "Error";
          }
        });
      } catch (error) {
        if (error === "Error") {
          return;
        }
      }
      //If not
      //Add All Of The User Info To The Database
      db.collection("Users").doc(username).set({
          fullName: fullName,
          username: username,
          password: password,
          phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
          emailAddress: emailAddress,
          chatsInvolvedIn: []
        })
        .then(function() {
          //If it succeeds, give user the heads up and then take them to their new homepage
          alert("Your account under the username " + username + " has been sucessfully created. You will now be redirected to your homepage.");
          //Place Code Underneath to Handle Keeping user Logged In For Present and Future Visits, along with redirecting to a homepage
          //Code Goes Here
          db.collection("Users").doc(username).get().then(function(doc) {
            if (doc.exists) {
              localStorage.setItem("loggedIn", JSON.stringify(doc.data()));
            }
            alert(localStorage.getItem("loggedIn"));
            //window.location.replace("index.html");
          });

        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          //If it fails, tell user to try again later (we don't care about the error message during production, because it is unlikely after our many tests)
          alert("I'm sorry but your account was not successfully created due to an unexpected error. Please try again later.");
        });

    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      //If checking the database originally for duplicate usernames fails, then give the user the same warning as above
      alert("I'm sorry but your account was not successfully created due to an unexpected error. Please try again later.");
    });
}
```

I know that my programming practices above aren't the best. if you could help me out, that would be great, thank you!

Comment: Is the above code in the global scope? i.e. in developer console, does `window.register` exist?

Comment: Yes. it is directly in between the `<script>` tags.

Comment: in the developer console, type *exactly* `register+''` is the response your code?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes! What do I do with this information?

Comment: nothing, I just wanted to be sure it's defined correctly - if the answer were "no", then I'd have something to work with, but since the function exists, I have no clue

Comment: Oh, ok. This whole function was working a while ago, and I used Git to retrace my steps, but now the whole function has just disappeared to the JS Interpreter.

Comment: I suggest a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It helps *you* with debugging, and it helps *us* make the best use of our time helping you.